# How do I get a pH of 2 with 37% HCl?

Tags: ph

I am following a guide on seed germination of a rare wild species. Others who have worked with the seeds suggest soaking at pH 2 (adjusting with HCl). I have a stock solution of 37% HCl and I want to make 250 ml of solution total. How much distilled water and how much HCl should I add to get a pH of 2?

Comment: pH is equal to $2$ if the concentration is equal to $0.01$ mol/L (= $0.365$ g HCl/L)

Comment: Thank you for your help @Maurice. I found online that 37% HCl = 12 mol/L.  So I could essentially pipette 0.12 mL HCl to every 1 mL of water? So if I wanted 250 mL total solution I would multiply 0.12 * 250 = 30 mL HCl?

Comment: No, it means you need to dilute the acid 1200 times.

Comment: No, that's not how all of it works. You grab 1 L of your 37% acid; that's 12 mol. You divide that by 12; that's 1 mol. You divide it further by 100, that would be 0.01 mol, and that's how much (or how little, actually) of it you need per 1 L of water.

Comment: Thank you for your patience with me, LOL! So if I read this right, Mithoron and Ivan Neretin are saying the same thing. 1 part HCl  to 1200 parts water. It's crazy that such a small amount of acid still has such a low pH!!!

Comment: Just a side note regarding this sentence "suggest soaking at pH 2 (adjusting with HCl)". Usually, when people say 'adjusting with', they mean that you measure the pH and adjust it to the desired value by adding something, in this case HCl. But I don't know the details or constraints of your experiment. In any case, be warned that given the relatively low (0.01 M) concentration of HCl in your solution, if you then add to it a significant amount of something that contains bases, the pH can vary, it's not buffered. E.g. even a very small amount of ammonia would dramatically alter the pH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting together all the helpful comments into a single answer! Thanks to @Maurice we know that 2 pH = 0.01 mol/L). We can use that in @Ivan Neretin comment who says to divide 1 L of HCl by 12 (the molarity of 37% HCl), then divide that again by 100. This concurs with the comment by @Mithoron who suggests diluting the HCl 1200 times.

So, to get 250 mL of solution with a pH of 2 using 37% HCl, I would divide 250 by 1200 = 0.21 mL HCl.

Comment: @Mithoron I agree that some editing is required. I returned the post to its original state.